# ERC20 RefundableCrowdsale

Tags: solidity, erc-20, truffle-test, openzeppelin-contracts

I have a crowdsale contract that inherits `RefundableCrowdsale.sol` from OpenZeppelin. I was using their v1.10.0 initially, but now revamping it using v1.12.0.

`contract TestTokenCrowdsale is Crowdsale, MintedCrowdsale, CappedCrowdsale, TimedCrowdsale, WhitelistedCrowdsale, RefundableCrowdsale { ... }`

and wrote a test script to test refunds.

In v1.10.0 this worked:

```
const RefundVault = artifacts.require('./RefundVault');

contract('TestTokenCrowdsale', function(accounts) {
    beforeEach(async function () {
        ...
        this.goal = ether(50);

        this.crowdsale = await TestTokenCrowdsale.new(
            ...
            this.goal
        );

        // Track refund vault
        this.vaultAddress = await this.crowdsale.vault();
        this.vault = RefundVault.at(this.vaultAddress);
    )};

    describe('during crowdsale', function() {
      it('prevents other accounts from claiming refund', async function() {
        await this.vault.refund(accounts[2], { from: accounts[2]}).should.be.rejectedWith(EVMRevert);
      });
    });    
}
```

But in v1.12.0 `RefundVault.sol` has changed to `RefundEscrow.sol`.

Before, I could track refund vault in `beforeEach`.

```
this.vaultAddress = await this.crowdsale.vault();
this.vault = RefundVault.at(this.vaultAddress);
```

This was possible because `this.crowdsale.vault()` is [public](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.10.0/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/RefundableCrowdsale.sol#L22) in v1.10.0. However, since in v1.12.0 `escrow` became [private](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/RefundableCrowdsale.sol#L21), I'm not sure how to modify it accordingly.

`this.vault.refund` won't work either because they removed `refund` in v1.12.0 as well.

How can I change to test `prevents other accounts from claiming refund` in v1.12.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest you look at the OpenZeppelin v1.12 test for RefundableCrowdsale for how to test that refunds are denied.
[RefundableCrowdsale.test.js](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.12.0/test/crowdsale/RefundableCrowdsale.test.js)

```
  it('should deny refunds before end', async function () {
    await expectThrow(this.crowdsale.claimRefund({ from: investor }), EVMRevert);
    await increaseTimeTo(this.openingTime);
    await expectThrow(this.crowdsale.claimRefund({ from: investor }), EVMRevert);
  });

  it('should deny refunds after end if goal was reached', async function () {
    await increaseTimeTo(this.openingTime);
    await this.crowdsale.sendTransaction({ value: goal, from: investor });
    await increaseTimeTo(this.afterClosingTime);
    await expectThrow(this.crowdsale.claimRefund({ from: investor }), EVMRevert);
  });
```

You may want to look at moving to [OpenZeppelin 2.2](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/releases/tag/v2.2.0)

Also [OpenZeppelin 2.3 RC3](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/releases/tag/v2.3.0-rc.3)

If you have more questions about OpenZeppelin you can always ask in the [forum](https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/)